# How to hide error 403 (but it works) with pusher`s + laravel`s private channel?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

How can I hide error 403 forbidden using private channel with laravel + pusher ?

### Situation

I have users on my page who can receive a message and others who cannot - this is checked through channels.php conditions, for example

```
Broadcast::channel('post.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
  return *my expresion*;
});
```

If the returns false , than I have error :

> `POST http://realtime/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)`

I do not want others to see it.

I have tried to make middleware **auth:api** but it doesn't work. And because of this middleware, it even doesn't work

#### Code

```
// routes/channels.php
Broadcast::channel('post.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) \App\Post::find($id)->user_id;
});
```

```
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes();

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

on the events folder I have NewComment event that implements ShouldBroadcast and have broadcastWith and broadcastOn:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('post.' . $this->comment->post->id);
}
```

and I use **vue.js**:

```
var channel = Echo.private('post.' + this.post.id);
channel.listen('NewComment', (comment) => {
    console.log(comment);
});
```

I want any users to visit the page do not see the error. But only specific can use the channel. Now it works but users that cant use channel have error 403 forbidden